# US Passport Card not yet received

Tags: usa, us-citizens, passport-renewals

I recently renewed my passport.  I requested, paid for, and the check was cleared by my bank for this service and a passport card.  My newly renewed passport book was received yesterday.  I have not yet received the expired passport book nor the passport card. Does anyone know if the passport card is also mailed separately?  Or might I receive the card when the old document is sent separately?

Comment: What is "recent"? How long has it been since you sent off your old information? Anecdotally, I typically receive the new passport first, and the old follows within a week or so.

Answer (score 12):

According to Section F of the instructions on [form DS-82 for a US passport renewal](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds82.pdf): (emphasis in original)

> *You may receive your newly issued U.S. passport book and/or card and your citizenship evidence in two separate mailings.* If you are applying for both a book and card, you may receive three separate mailings: one with your returned evidence, one with your newly issued book, and one with your newly issued card. **All documentary evidence that is not damaged, altered, or forged will be returned to you.** Photocopies will not be returned.

So it is completely normal and expected to receive up to three mailings if you are applying for a passport book and card: one with the book, one with the card, and one with your old passport and other submitted evidence. They may arrive on different days, and I would not worry if it has been only a couple of days since you received the first of these mailings.

Comment: I believe passport cards are manufactured by a different company, so it is even possible there’s a bigger gap between mailings depending on capacity/backlogs at the different facilities and different mail transit times.

Comment: Thank you very much MLC!

Comment: I can confirm all of this - I did this about a year ago, and three mailings at separate times, the passport card came last I believe.